# Css is not applied when YII_DEBUG is set to false

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii, production-environment

I have a website made using Yii plus YiiBooster. When I am in DEBUG mode there is no problem - all styles loads and applys properly. When I set YII_DEBUG to false in index.php file - css files are still showed as loaded by the FireBug but it seems all of those styles are not applied.

Why? How to fix it?

EDIT:
I can see now the problem is in bootstrap.min.css. It is not the same as the bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 3):

I got it. When you are in production mode bootstrap.min.css is being used instead of bootstrap.css. The bootstrap.min.css file wasn't complete so the layout was broken. I just minified again bootstrap.css and it runs fine now.